# Angular: pass dynamic parameter to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to find out how I can pass a parameter that was dynamically created using ng-repeat back to the controller by calling a controller function.

Currently when I call `showItem('{{item.item_id}}');` I see `{{item.item_id}}` in my controller function. If I leave the parenthesis off, it seems like the function is not being called (no output in console.log).

```js
$scope.showItem = function(itemId) {
  console.log('show item '+itemId);
 }
```

```html
<ul ng-repeat="items in data">
  <li>
    <a ng-click="showItem('{{items.item_id}}')" href="javascript:void(0);" >
      {{items.name}}
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it without interpolation:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in data">
  <li>
    <a ng-click="showItem(item.item_id)" href="javascript:void(0);">
      {{item.name}}
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a ng-click="showItem(item.item_id)" href="">
```

Note that an empty href is all you need to prevent navigation.

Also note that you could have found that by looking at [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), which explains what ng-click expects (an expression), and has examples.

Comment: I love your answers. Always follow your answer as learning tip for angularJS.

Comment: I tried to make the samething here is my example. Simplified code.

<div data-ng-repeat="indicator in competence.indicators" class="content level2">

<a ng-click="listAllRestulatsByIndicateurId(indicator.id)" href="javascript:void(0);">Click me</a>

</div>


But my HTML do not write the correct parameter in the function. I tried to show it with {{indicator.id}} and it worked.